# How to add style attribute in xsl by @variable

Tags: xslt

I have a variable @expectedLength. I need to assign it to a style attribute.

```
            <xsl:if test="@expectedLength">
               <xsl:attribute name="style">
                  <xsl:value-of select="'width:200px'"/>
               </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
```

I need to replace 200 with the value of @expectedLength. How can I use the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your snippet to

```
<xsl:if test="@expectedLength">
  <xsl:attribute name="style">width: <xsl:value-of select="@expectedLength"/>;</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

That should work with any version of XSLT.

In XSLT 2 and later you can also use the `select` expression

```
<xsl:if test="@expectedLength">
  <xsl:attribute name="style" select="concat('width: ', @expectedLength, ';')"/>
</xsl:if>
```

I would prefer to and suggest to set up a template

```
<xsl:template match="@expectedLength">
  <xsl:attribute name="style" select="concat('width: ', @expectedLength, ';')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and then to make sure higher up that any attribute nodes are processed.